# How to make JS only output once

Tags: javascript

I made a website where if you input when you were born, it outputs your age in days. The problem is that, if you keep inputting again and again, the output ends up clogging your screen. I want JS to only output once. Here is my JS Code:

```
function ageInDays() {
    // variables
    var birthYear = document.getElementById("input-id").value;
    var thisYear = new Date();
    var ageInDayss = (thisYear.getFullYear() - birthYear) * 365;


    //text
    if (isNaN(birthYear) == false) {
        if (birthYear<=1920 || birthYear>=2022) {  
            var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
            var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("Invalid Input. Please Try 
            Again.");
            h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
            h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
            document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
    }
    
    else if (birthYear>=1990 && birthYear<=2021) {
        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDayss + " days 
        old.");
        h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);

    } 


    else if (birthYear>1920 && birthYear<1990) {
        var h1 = document.createElement('span');
        var h2 = document.createElement('span');
        var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDayss + " days 
        old.");
        var textAnswer1 = document.createTextNode(" Yikes... that's old.");
        h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
        h2.setAttribute('id', 'yikes');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        h2.appendChild(textAnswer1);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1).appendChild(h2);
    }

}else if (birthYear = "string"){
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("Invalid Input. Please Try Again.");
    h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
    h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
    document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
 }
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove();
}
```

So, I want JS to only output once. How do I do that?

Comment: Don't use appendChild?

Comment: What can I use instead of appendChild to output the output.

Comment: If you only ever want one output at a time? `myElement.replaceChildren(replacementNode)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren

Comment: Write this as an answer with more detail.

Comment: It's not an answer, only a suggestion.

Comment: Can you add detail to your suggestion? I don't fully understand it. How will the replaceChildren thing work?

Comment: Using `replaceChildren` instead of `appendChild` replaces the children with the element instead of appending the element to the children.

Comment: It's not working. Can you post an example?

Comment: Instead of creating and appending elements everytime you could have one `h1` element inside the `flex-box-result` and then only update its [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) for each case.